# How do I reference an arbitrary id<MTLTexture> for use in a SCNTechnique?

Tags: 3d, shader, scenekit, metal

**TL;DR:**

How does one reference a 'not on disk' sampler2D symbol and pass it to an `SCNTechnique`? My technique works if I reference an image from my bundle, but if I don't, I cannot find a way to pass in an existing `id<MTLTexture>` to the sampler symbol my technique has set up.

**Long:**

I have a valid working `SCNTechnique` which uses a custom sampler2D symbol as an input to my metal fragment pass. I am attempting to pass in an external (not from Scenekit) `id<MTLTexture>` that I get from a hardware sensor as input in a post process pass.

Following the `SCNShadable` docs which state an `id<MTLTexture>` can be passed as a shader input via an `SCNMaterialProperty` which has the proper contents set. This 100% works in a shader modifier pass - but fails for `SCNTecnique`!

```
let texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(textureRef!)

if self.material == nil
{
    self.material = SCNMaterialProperty(contents:texture)
}
else
{
    self.material?.contents = texture
}

self.currentTechnique?.setObject(self.material, forKeyedSubscript: "myTextureSamplerSymbol" as NSCopying)
```

For a `SCNTechnique`, I get error logs indicating "No Storage for texture" and the Metal GPU frame capture indicates there is a default 4x4 pixel white texture set for the sampler (presumably from the `SCNTecnique`?). However, I've been able to validate that my custom `id<MTLTexture>` is valid and has contents in the debugger - its format, width, height and contents all are as expected, I just can't seem to reference an arbitrary texture into a scene kit technique pass correctly.

If I declare my symbol in the `SCNTechnique` plist file to reference an image like so:

```
<dict>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>sampler2D</string>
    <key>image</key>
    <string>star.png</string>
</dict>
```

And my pass inputs like so:

```
<dict>
    <key>colorSampler</key>
    <string>COLOR</string>
    <key>depthSampler</key>
    <string>DEPTH</string>
    <key> myTextureSampler</key>
    <dict>
        <key>target</key>
        <string> myTextureSamplerSymbol </string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then my pass works and the star.png texture referenced.

Has anyone gotten something like this to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly certain I got this working.

Swift code to setup the `MTLTexture` and set it into the `SCNTechnique`.

```
let tech:SCNTechnique = getTechnique()

let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gradient", withExtension: "png")!

do {
    let gradTexture: MTLTexture = try textureLoader.newTexture(URL: filePath, options: nil)
    let matPropTexture = SCNMaterialProperty(contents: gradTexture)
    tech.setObject(matPropTexture, forKeyedSubscript: "myTexture" as NSCopying)
} catch {
    print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
}

scnView.technique = tech
```

`gradient.png` is a 256 x 1px color gradient (blue -> green -> red) image I use to map a single value to a pseudo colour.
(eg; [image] )

Here's a complete technique pass definition from the passes dict in my plist.

```
<key>mix_outline</key>
<dict>
    <key>draw</key>
    <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
    <key>metalVertexShader</key>
    <string>pass_through_vertex</string>
    <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
    <string>mix_outline_fragment</string>
    <key>inputs</key>
    <dict>
        <key>colorSampler</key>
        <string>color_scene</string>
        <key>depthSampler</key>
        <string>depth_outline</string>
        <key>myTextureSampler</key>
        <string>myTexture</string>
    </dict>
    <key>outputs</key>
    <dict>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>COLOR</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

`myTexture` needs to be defined in the symbols section of the technique plist also.

```
<key>symbols</key>
<dict>
    <key>myTexture</key>
    <dict>
        <key>type</key>
        <string>sampler2D</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

*I too saw the "pass has no storage for input myTextureSampler" error message when this symbols block was not included.* **This may be your problem?**

And lastly the fragment shader definition.

```
fragment half4 mix_outline_fragment(out_vertex_t vert [[stage_in]],
                                    texture2d<float, access::sample> colorSampler [[texture(0)]],
                                    texture2d<float, access::sample> depthSampler [[texture(1)]],
                                    texture2d<float, access::sample> myTextureSampler [[texture(2)]])
{
    float4 myTextureColor = myTextureSampler.read(uint2(55, 0));
    float4 outline = depthSampler.sample( s, vert.uv);
    float4 scene_color = colorSampler.sample( s, vert.uv);
    // float4 fragment_color = mix(scene_color, float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), outline.r);
    float4 fragment_color = mix(scene_color, myTextureColor, outline.r);
    return half4(fragment_color);
}
```

There's a few other passes involved in this technique that I haven't included; just to give some context it renders the scene in one pass and uses the output depth buffer in another pass with a Sobel operator to generate edges into the `depthSampler` texture. The above pass + fragment shader draws these edges on top of the original rendering of the scene. I was using solid black for the edges, but after looking into this it seems I'm able to read a color out of the `MTLTexture` I provide to the `SCNTechnique` and use it for the edges.

Comment: This is *super* helpful - thank you. I'll check this out today and report back / mark as right if so. Its unclear to me from looking at your code and mine what the hell I am doing wrong - maybe the lifetime of my sensor's texture is weird? Ill report back :) Thank you!

Comment: Ok, your approach 100% works with a texture loaded from disk but as an application owned (as opposed to SCNTecnique owned) id<MTLTexture> , so im going to mark this as correct - I suspect that either when I update the SCNMaterialPropertyContents or the lifetime of my textures is to blame for the error. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of updating the `SCNMaterialProperty.contents` I'd probably suggest updating the MTLTexture itself (even if blitting a new texture into the one you've passed to the technique. Another issue could be where the map prop contents are updated; I'd make sure it's in something like the [updateAtTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate/1522937-renderer) delegate method.